# What is the best ASP.NET MVC View Engine?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, viewengine

Till ASP.NET MVC 3, Microsoft uses **ASP.NET View Engine** for MVC. henceforth they changed it to **Razor**.

Yet, there are many other view engines such as:

- Spark
- NHaml
- SharpDOM
- SharpTiles
- Wing Beats
- string-template-view-engine-mvc
- Bellevue
- Brail
- Hasic
- NDjango
- ...

What's the difference between these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing like "best" view engine. Each of them has their own advantages and problems. If you really want to know which of theses is best suitable for you, then you have to try them. We can't tell you which one to choose beacuse our perception is biased on our unique experience :)

Comment: I'm asking this to understand the advantages